# Recoll won't start

Tags: 12.04, recoll

Whenever I try to open `recoll`, I get a popup box with this message:

```
Configuration problem: Configuration could not be built:
Explicitly specified configuration must exist (won't be automatically created)
```

and I get this as stderr:

```
$ recoll
Got bus address:  "unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-GO0LJ4yYcr,guid=e695867e0d6df401c0df2baf0000dd87" 
Connected to accessibility bus at:  "unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-GO0LJ4yYcr,guid=e695867e0d6df401c0df2baf0000dd87" 
Registered DEC:  true 
:4:main.cpp:143:recollCleanup: writing settings
```

I've tried deleting the `.recoll` folder and running `sudo apt-get purge recoll && sudo apt-get install recoll`, but they didn't help.

Update: version information.

```
$ apt-cache policy recoll
recoll:
  Installed: 1.16.2-1
  Candidate: 1.16.2-1
  Version table:
 *** 1.16.2-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

Update 2: Created bug report.

https://bitbucket.org/medoc/recoll/issue/168/recoll-wont-load-even-after-removing

Addendum: the issue was that I had this in my `~/.profile`:

```
export RECOLL_CONFDIR='~/.recoll'
```

Since the `~/.recoll` folder didn't already exist on my system, `recoll` quite reasonably showed an error.

Comment: It might be helpful if you included what version of Ubuntu and recoll are installed on your system.

Comment: If you did anything interesting with your repos, it would also be good to know which repo recoll came from. (apt-cache policy recoll).

Comment: Have you got RECOLL_CONFDIR in your environment by any chance ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unset RECOLL_CONFDIR, or create the target directory. Recoll will not create a configuration directory which was specified through the environment or the command line (only the implicitly defined default configuration directory will be automatically created).